# Displaying "Vscode-made" R graphic on R Graph

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I use R in Vscode and when I click to show the created graphic, Vscode opens the image on Vscode itself. Im already using httpgd for better visualization, but I would like that the image opened on R Graph, out of Vscode(it was doing that before I reseted my PC, but not anymore).

Comment: I'm either unable to reproduce or perhaps understand what your setup might be. I just did a fresh install of VSCode and installed the R extension on my Ubuntu box with the .deb package. When I run R from the VSCode IDE Terminal  and execute `plot(1,1)` , I get an R plot window. You say you are "using httpgd" but what that means is totally unclear to me as a new user of VSCode. (There appears a separate R icon on the task list that lets you bring the plot window to the fore.)

Comment: If I understood that correctly, you are getting the response I wanted, a new whole R tab, outside of Vscode, showing the plot. Do you think it is because of the .deb package, or the plot(1,1) command, or both?

Comment: How can I know? You have not described what you did in any detail or what your setup was.

Comment: I have created a box plot in R language in Vscode, when I use the command to plot it (show the created graphic), it opens up in a tab called "plot" INSIDE Vscode. However, I wanted the graphic to be shown OUTSIDE Vscode, on R graph, an in-built R program, that displays created graphics, but I dont know how. That's pretty much it.

Comment: **How** did you “create a box plot in VSCode”? I need details about the code and where it was entered and what sort of pull down menus. Try to imagine that you are telling this to a smart 9th grade student. I can provably attempt to duplicate your actions in a Linux or Mac box.